# DB schema for team scheduling

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to DBs and would just like a yay/nay on my approach. I'm using postgres.

I have the following tables

```
schedules 
   schedule_id SERIAL PK
   team

Events
  event_id SERIAL PK,
  title,
  start_time, 
  end_time, 
  schedule_id (foreign key relationship to schedules.schedule_id)
```

When I want all the events for a particular team I do a LEFT JOIN like this:

```
SELECT 
   events.event_id,
   events.title,
   events.start_time,
   events.end_time,
   events.schedule_id,
   schedules.schedule_id
FROM
   events
LEFT JOIN schedules ON events .schedule_id = schedule.schedule_id;
```

Does this make sense?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only change I would suggest is to look at using interval types instead of start and end time if you can use PostgreSQL 9.2 or higher.